# How to set a specific position for a leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have been doing some mapping with Leaflet and I'm super happy with the result.

However, there is just one little thing that has been bothering me:

I have got two different circles, with popups bound to them, and depending on where I click on the circle, the popup opens in a different location...

[image: Image showing the map with popup at the top]
[image: Image showing the popup at a different position]

Here is some super simple example code.

```js
const circle = new L.circle( [52.5, 13.35] ).addTo(map);
var popup = L.popup().setContent("hello");
```

I have also tried `var popup = L.popup().setLatLng( [52.5, 13.35] ).setContent("hello");`

So is there a (preferably) easy way to make the popup box open at the middle of the circle (or have the middle of the circle as the 'anchor point'), so that where ever I click on the circle the popup always opens at the same place?

Very minor, but would appreciate any help, or directions towards a library,

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me quote the [Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layer-openpopup) about the `openPopup` method that every `L.Layer` (including every `L.Circle`) has:

> `openPopup(<LatLng> latlng?)`
>
> Opens the bound popup at the specified `latlng` or at the default popup anchor if no `latlng` is passed.

Therefore you can:

```
const circle = new L.circle( [52.5, 13.35] ).bindPopup("hello").addTo(map);
circle.openPopup([52.5, 13.35]);
```

or

```
const circle = new L.circle( [52.5, 13.35] ).bindPopup("hello").addTo(map);
circle.openPopup(circle.getLatLng());
```

or

```
const circle = new L.circle( [52.5, 13.35] ).bindPopup("hello").addTo(map);
circle.on('click', function(ev) { circle.openPopup(circle.getLatLng()) });
```

or even

```
const circle = new L.circle( [52.5, 13.35] ).bindPopup("hello").addTo(map);
circle.on('click', function(ev) { ev.target.openPopup(ev.target.getLatLng()) });
```

See a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/H92BT8jJKSTswdoi).

Comment: I don't understand why we need to add an `onclick` to the `popup` since it is already implemented by Leaflet. The first 2 options of this answer will open the popup upon creation which might not be desirable. And the third one adds an unnecessary `onclick`event. Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's not about opening the popup - it's about opening the popup *in a specific position*. The way to do so is to *not* rely on the default behaviour.